# Error encountered during contract execution [contract creation code storage out of gas]

Tags: web3js

Transaction Hash: 0xa67bab86a7249fe3e332c32507cd575c3fff3fd7da2134b04bbab35ea5815ed0

Can someone help me with this?

That i used for my 0.15 bnb
0x34f91c17d280b908dfa61eac10c69806b91d8eeed0b3f2ba4c690e8ed0b7e24a

i dont received or get my invest back...  :(

https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmeEpHxvEtnK5bRbiPfHoPBPd8AKdd5whTPUofE3hEpYMu

Is it possible to cancellation https://bscscan.com/tx/0x34f91c17d280b908dfa61eac10c69806b91d8eeed0b3f2ba4c690e8ed0b7e24a this transaction from my metamask?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see. This is a contract deployment that failed.
It used up 100% of the gas you provide and could probably not complete the task. So it reverted.

Gas you spend on contract creation or function call is what you spent to get the EVM to work. It is spent and cannot be cancelled or retrieved.

So you need to provide more gas for your deployment.

Look into  gasLimit and gasprice argument when you make the call.

Comment: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x34f91c17d280b908dfa61eac10c69806b91d8eeed0b3f2ba4c690e8ed0b7e24a
Its about those .15 BnB. I didn't get it back - its accepted ..
I tried many times to add more fee or is it after first input of gas in a different universe? :P

Comment: Where do you sent this to? i don't see it in the balance of your contract?